# Symfony + Switfmailer, It doesnt send emails

Tags: php, symfony, email, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

I am trying to send emails in my web app using FOSUserBundle.

When I register a new user a flash message from FOSUserBundle is showed (email successfully sended) but when I check the debug toolbar:

[image]

The email is not received:

> **Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com**

could someone help me?

My configuration is `config.yml`:

```
#Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport:  "%mailer_transport%"
    username:   "%mailer_user%"
    password:   "%mailer_password%"
    spool:      { type: memory }

#FOSUser
fos_user:
    from_email:
        address:     "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"

    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
```

My `parameters.yml` is:

```
parameters:
    # ...Database config...

    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_user: nick@gmail.com
    mailer_password: pass
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Notes:

> - I have activated "Allow or prevent less secure applications from accessing accounts" on Gmail.
> - I assumed SwitfMailer is included in the installation of **Symfony in 3.4** version.

Comment: The profiler page you are showing in the image is redirected from /register endpoint where the mail is sent. You can access the other profiler page by pressing the **Last 10** button or usually a token with a link should appear after the **redirect from** text . So in order to see if the mail is sent you must check the profiler of the page **localhost:8000/register/**

Comment: @knetsi the debbuger says: "Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com" Do you know why? I am going to update my answer.

Comment: The error is that smtp.gmail.com can't be connected to. Debug that first, can you connect on the command line with that mailhost? With the same connection info? Then, ask if the configuration you're using works, once you know you can connect to that account on the same server.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I put on the command line "php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send" and I completed all fields. Then: app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0] what sould I do Jared?

Comment: I meant connect with telnet.

Comment: @Mich do you use 2 step verification on your gmail account? Take a look at this documentation https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/email/gmail.html#redefining-the-default-configuration-parameters note that you may have to override some configurations

Comment: You're not using a SMTP server but try to connect to a account, try creating the Swift_SmtpTransport with ->setAuthMode('login') or directly auth_mode: 'login' in the config.yml

Comment: I can do ping to smtp.gmail.com, but the error says to me that my host can't resolve the domain. @JaredFarrish

Comment: I didnt activate two step account verification option @knetsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time looking for a solution on internet and here, this works for me **config.yml**:

```
  swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    stream_options:
        ssl:
            allow_self_signed: true
            verify_peer: false
            verify_peer_name: false
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

PD: This solution is not advised in a production environment.